# C++: PlaySound() gives 100+ compilation errors

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, playsound

I am trying to play a sound in C++. When I use the PlaySound() function, Visual Studio gives 100+ compilation errors (I know this because the compiler stops at 100 errors). Below is my code:

```cpp
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    bool played = PlaySound(TEXT("sound.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio's linter also gives the error:

```
identifier PlaySoundW is undefined
```

This is the compilation output:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(94,30): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(94,21): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'MMVERSION'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(98,32): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(98,32): error C2059: syntax error: 'return'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(102,20): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(102,27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(112,21): error C3646: 'ms': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(112,23): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(113,21): error C3646: 'sample': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(113,27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(114,21): error C3646: 'cb': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(114,23): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(115,21): error C3646: 'ticks': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(115,26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(120,21): error C3646: 'hour': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(120,25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(121,21): error C3646: 'min': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(121,24): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(122,21): error C3646: 'sec': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(122,24): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(123,21): error C3646: 'frame': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(123,26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(124,21): error C3646: 'fps': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(124,24): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(125,21): error C3646: 'dummy': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(125,26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(127,21): error C3646: 'pad': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(127,24): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '['
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(127,27): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(134,19): error C3646: 'songptrpos': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(134,29): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(137,26): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(137,35): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(137,41): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(137,41): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(137,41): error C2377: 'FAR': redefinition; typedef cannot be overloaded with any other symbol
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(102): message : see declaration of 'FAR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(137,50): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(275,21): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(275,16): error C2065: 'HDRVR': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(297,24): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'DRVCALLBACK'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(297,24): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'DRVCALLBACK'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(297,35): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(297,43): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(297,37): error C2065: 'HDRVR': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(297,43): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'hdrvr'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(299,25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(299,25): error C2378: 'DRVCALLBACK': redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(297): message : see declaration of 'DRVCALLBACK'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(299,21): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'FAR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(299,25): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(299,21): error C2086: 'int FAR': redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(137): message : see declaration of 'FAR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(299,39): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(301,25): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(301,25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(301,25): error C2378: 'DRVCALLBACK': redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(297): message : see declaration of 'DRVCALLBACK'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(301,38): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(37,25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(37,17): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'MCIERROR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(45,24): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(45,24): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(45,15): error C2371: 'CALLBACK': redefinition; different basic types
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(297): message : see declaration of 'CALLBACK'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(45,34): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(45,73): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(52,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(51,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'MCIERROR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(62,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(60,1): error C2086: 'int DECLSPEC_IMPORT': redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(50): message : see declaration of 'DECLSPEC_IMPORT'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(61,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'MCIERROR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(77,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(75,1): error C2086: 'int DECLSPEC_IMPORT': redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(50): message : see declaration of 'DECLSPEC_IMPORT'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(76,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'MCIERROR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(87,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(85,1): error C2086: 'int DECLSPEC_IMPORT': redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(50): message : see declaration of 'DECLSPEC_IMPORT'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(86,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'MCIERROR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(102,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(100,1): error C2086: 'int DECLSPEC_IMPORT': redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(50): message : see declaration of 'DECLSPEC_IMPORT'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(101,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'MCIDEVICEID'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(109,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(107,1): error C2086: 'int DECLSPEC_IMPORT': redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(50): message : see declaration of 'DECLSPEC_IMPORT'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(108,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'MCIDEVICEID'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(121,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(119,1): error C2086: 'int DECLSPEC_IMPORT': redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(50): message : see declaration of 'DECLSPEC_IMPORT'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(120,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'MCIDEVICEID'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(129,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(127,1): error C2086: 'int DECLSPEC_IMPORT': redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(50): message : see declaration of 'DECLSPEC_IMPORT'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(128,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'MCIDEVICEID'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(142,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(140,1): error C2086: 'int DECLSPEC_IMPORT': redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(50): message : see declaration of 'DECLSPEC_IMPORT'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(141,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'BOOL'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(151,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(149,1): error C2086: 'int DECLSPEC_IMPORT': redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(50): message : see declaration of 'DECLSPEC_IMPORT'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(150,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'BOOL'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(173,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(171,1): error C2086: 'int DECLSPEC_IMPORT': redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(50): message : see declaration of 'DECLSPEC_IMPORT'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(172,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'BOOL'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(202,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(200,1): error C2086: 'int DECLSPEC_IMPORT': redefinition
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(50): message : see declaration of 'DECLSPEC_IMPORT'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(201,1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'BOOL'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(499,17): error C3646: 'dwCallback': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(499,27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(500,47): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(500,43): error C2371: 'FAR': redefinition; different basic types
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(137): message : see declaration of 'FAR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(500,67): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(507,17): error C3646: 'dwCallback': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(507,27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(509,16): error C3646: 'lpstrDeviceType': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(509,31): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(510,16): error C3646: 'lpstrElementName': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(510,32): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(511,16): error C3646: 'lpstrAlias': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(511,26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(514,17): error C3646: 'dwCallback': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(514,27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(516,16): error C3646: 'lpstrDeviceType': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(516,31): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(517,16): error C3646: 'lpstrElementName': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(517,32): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(518,16): error C3646: 'lpstrAlias': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(518,26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(544,17): error C3646: 'dwCallback': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(544,27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(547,41): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(547,37): error C2371: 'FAR': redefinition; different basic types
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(137): message : see declaration of 'FAR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(547,58): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(552,17): error C3646: 'dwCallback': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(552,27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(554,41): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(554,37): error C2371: 'FAR': redefinition; different basic types
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(137): message : see declaration of 'FAR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(554,58): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(559,17): error C3646: 'dwCallback': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(559,27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(560,17): error C3646: 'dwReturn': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(560,25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(563,45): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(563,41): error C2371: 'FAR': redefinition; different basic types
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(137): message : see declaration of 'FAR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(563,65): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(570,15): error C3646: 'dwCallback': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(570,25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(571,15): error C3646: 'lpstrReturn': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(571,26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(575,15): error C3646: 'dwCallback': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(575,25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(576,15): error C3646: 'lpstrReturn': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(576,26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(598,17): error C3646: 'dwCallback': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(598,27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(601,53): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(601,49): error C2371: 'FAR': redefinition; different basic types
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(137): message : see declaration of 'FAR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(601,77): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(608,17): error C3646: 'dwCallback': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(608,27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(609,17): error C3646: 'lpstrReturn': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(609,28): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(615,17): error C3646: 'dwCallback': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(615,27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(616,17): error C3646: 'lpstrReturn': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(616,28): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(644,17): error C3646: 'dwCallback': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(644,27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(647,39): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(647,35): error C2371: 'FAR': redefinition; different basic types
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(137): message : see declaration of 'FAR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(647,55): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(652,17): error C3646: 'dwCallback': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(652,27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(655,17): error C3646: 'hwndBreak': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(655,26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(662,43): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(662,39): error C2371: 'FAR': redefinition; different basic types
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mmsyscom.h(137): message : see declaration of 'FAR'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(662,62): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(669,18): error C3646: 'dwCallback': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(669,28): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(670,18): error C3646: 'lpfilename': unknown override specifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\mciapi.h(670,28): fatal  error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

How do I prevent these compilation errors?

Comment: Have you tried including <windows.h> before <mmsystem.h>?

Comment: Headers SHOULD be consistent and include everything they need, sadly Microsoft didn't get the memo back in the stone ages and now we're stuck with this <expletive deleted>ed-up behaviour. Mind you, there could be some interesting tactical reasons for requiring this ordering that's beyond my ken.

Comment: @AviBerger thanks for your help, I managed to get it working.

Comment: @user4581301 I've always presumed that it was to allow tailoring of windows.h by defining macros before its inclusion. Considering the case that I can think of (WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN), that really doesn't hold up too well. Maybe it was assumed to be obvious that the "base" header would be included first and not thought about beyond that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include `<windows.h>` first, then `<mmsystem.h>`